# Excel To python OR Excel to Database

Tags: python, excel

I have a spreadsheet with live data being updated continuously. Is there a way to read that data in to python without actually having to save the spreadsheet everytime? `openpyxl` allows me to import the workbook but every time that spreadsheets get updated with new data, unless i save it, I can't just call the spreadsheet and via `load_workbook()`. If I do, it just loads the version of the spreadsheet that was last saved.

The goal is to take snapshots of the data from the spreadsheet and save it to the database continuously every 1 minute etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Check out xlwings (https://www.xlwings.org/). It can work with cells and ranges live in a document.

Comment: I do not think this is possible. Python reads the file from disk, not from memory, unless you find a way to make python read the data from memory directly.

Comment: yea thats my thought. I think the more robust way to do it is via python and push the data to excel.